# How to permanently delete specific file after specific number of days after running the script in a batch file

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, file-io, cmd

I would like to have a little batch file script which will work on **Windows XP,7,8** and delete any occurrences of a specific file after a certain amount of time after the script is executed.

I have tried something similar:

`forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *somefile.pdf* /D -<number of days> /C "cmd /c del @path"`

But this isn't what I'm actually looking for as it is deleting files older than a specific time. Any useful advice ?

Comment: So the script will be *running in background for a few days* and then it automatically will delete the file?

Comment: Yes, I think that this is the way. Do you have another suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically three ways to solve this problem:

- Keep the Batch file running all the time, delete the file after the desired time complete and restart the process. This is the method used in wOxxOm's answer.
- Use Windows Task Scheduler to execute the "delete file" command every N days.
- Place a Batch file in Startup folder so it run each time the user log in. The Batch file check if the file must be deleted to do it, calculate the date of the next time and store it in a companion data file. This is the method used in the Batch file below:

.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get today's date arranged as YYYYMMDD
rem (adjust lines below if MM/DD/YYYY is not the current locale date format)
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set "MM=%%a" & set "DD=%%b" & set "YYYY=%%c"
)
set "today=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"

rem Read next date from companion file
set /P nextDate=< NextDate.txt

if %today% lss %nextDate% goto :EOF

rem Delete the file, calculate next date and store it in companion file
del "C:\what\ever\somefile.pdf"

set days=5

set mon=0
for %%a in (31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31) do (
   set /A mon+=1
   set "daysPerMonth[!mon!]=%%a"
)
set /A Ymod4=YYYY %% 4, MM=1%MM% - 100, DD=1%DD% - 100 + days
if %Ymod4% equ 0 set "daysPerMonth[2]=29"
if %DD% gtr !daysPerMonth[%MM%]! set /A DD-=daysPerMonth[%MM%], MM+=1
if %MM% gtr 12 set /A MM=1, YYYY+=1
if %MM% lss 10 set "MM=0%MM%"
if %DD% lss 10 set "DD=0%DD%"

echo %YYYY%%MM%%DD%> NextDate.txt
```

Note that you must manually create the `NextDate.txt` file with the first date, although additional code may be inserted in order to manage this initialization step.

Answer (score 0):

Using only the built-in commands:

```
set days=5
for /L %%T in (1,1,%days%) do timeout 86400
del "C:\what\ever\*somefile.pdf*"
```

This will pause the execution of the batch file for the given number of days, then it'll delete the file(s).